# Refactoring Function in React with Parameters

Tags: function, checkbox, reactjs, refactoring

I have checkboxes which do similar things.

Functions:

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props);
    this.state = { 
       Dog:false,
       Cat:false,
       Fish:true,
       clickedAnimal:true 
    };
   this.checkCat = this.checkCat.bind(this);
   this.checkDog = this.checkDog.bind(this);
   this.checkFish = this.checkFish.bind(this);
 }

 checkCat(){
   this.setState({Cat: !this.state.Cat});   
 }
 checkDog(){
   this.setState({Dog: !this.state.Dog});   
 }
 checkFish(){
   this.setState({Fish: !this.state.Fish});   
 }
```

Checkboxes:

```
{this.state.clickedAnimal ? 
  <div className="animal-filter">

    <p><input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.Cat} onChange=  {this.checkCat)} /> Cat </p>

    <p><input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.Dog} onChange={this.checkDog} /> Dog</p>

    <p><input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.Fish} onChange={this.checkFish} /> Fish</p>

  </div> : null}
```

I want to refactor this into 1 function and feed it with a parameter: checkAnimal(animal)

However, I keep getting errors when I do something like this:

```
  <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.Fish} onChange={this.checkAnimal(Animal)} /> Fish
```

Is there a way to pass a parameter through a function in a checkbox tag like this?

--EDIT

This is the error I keep getting if I add a parameter to checkAnimal:

Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render`). Render methods should be a pure function of props.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a good opportunity for a higher-order function, which is a function that returns another function.

So your `checkAnimal` function might look like this:

```js
checkAnimal(animal) {
  return () => {
    this.setState({
      [animal]: !this.state[animal]
    }); 
  };
}
```

The square brace notation above is new ES6 "[computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names)" feature, which allows you to have dynamically generated object keys.

The result of running `this.checkAnimal('Cat')` will be a return value of:

```js
() => {
  this.setState({
    Cat: !this.state['Cat']
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! My problem is that the actual <input checkbox> tag does not accept parameters at all. So I can't get to this step.  I keep getting a "cannot update existing state transition" error

Comment: Could you post some more code in your question? Specifically your render method where your inputs are.

Comment: I just added the edits, I think the problem may be due to the clickedAnimal? conditional I have within the html. Thanks!